# Topological analysis of $A=\{\frac{n+\sqrt 2}{3n+\sqrt 3} | n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup (-3,0]$ with respect to the standard topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

I am asked to find the interior, the closure, the derived set and the boundary of $A=\{\frac{n+\sqrt 2}{3n+\sqrt 3} | n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup (-3,0]$ (this is not a homework problem, I am solving past real analysis exams). Then I have to say whether $A$ is connected or compact.
I will write here my solution because I want to see if I approach this problem correctly.  Let $x_n=  \frac{n+\sqrt 2}{3n+\sqrt 3}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
We firstly prove that the interior of $A$ is $(-3,0)$.
Since $(-3,0)\subset A$ and $(-3,0)$ is open, we get that it is contained in the interior set. Since the interior is a subset of $A$, we are left to prove that  $x_n$ is not in the interior for any $n$ and that $0$ is also not an interior point.
Suppose there is some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n$ is an interior point. Then there is some $r>0$ such that $(x_n-r, x_n+r)\subset A$. This implies that $(x_n-r, x_n+r)\cap (x_n, x_n+r)\subset A\cap (x_n, x_n+r)$. But $(x_n-r, x_n+r)\cap (x_n, x_n+r)=(x_n, x_n+r)$ is an infinite set, whilst $A\cap (x_n, x_n+r)$ is a finite set and we have reached a contradiction.
Now let's suppose that $0$ is an interior point of $A$. Then there is some $r>0$ such that $(-r,r)\subset A \implies (-r,r)\cap (0, x_1) \subset A \cap (0,x_1)$. The first set contains $r$, whilst the second one is empty (we are using the fact that the sequence $x_n$ is decreasing) and now we are done.
Now we prove that $\overline{A}=\{\frac{n+\sqrt 2}{3n+\sqrt 3} | n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup [-3,0]\cup \{\frac{1}{3}\}$.
We know that $A\subset \overline{A}$, so we only wish to prove that $-3$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ are in $\overline{A}$.
Since $x_n \to \frac{1}{3}$ we easily get that $\frac{1}{3}\in \overline{A}$.
$-3 \in \overline{A}$ because for any sets $\overline{X\cup Y}=\overline{X}\cup\overline{Y}$ and now we are done.
So, $A\subset B:=\{\frac{n+\sqrt 2}{3n+\sqrt 3} | n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup [-3,0]\cup \{\frac{1}{3}\}\subset \overline{A}$. Because $\displaystyle \mathcal{C}_B=(-\infty, -3)\cup (0, \frac{1}{3})\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n+1}, x_n)\cup (x_1, \infty)$, this set is open, so $B$ is closed and we get that $\overline{A}=B$.
Now we show that $A'=[-3,0]\cup \{\frac{1}{3}\}$. We don't have too much to do, because $\overline{A}=A\cup A'$, so we instantly get that $\frac{1}{3},-3\in A'$. Now we just want to show that $x_n$ is not in $A'$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Suppose there is some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in A'$. Let $r=\min\{x_n-x_{n+1}, x_{n-1}-x_n\}$. Then we have that $(x_n-r, x_n+r)\cap A \setminus \{x_n\}=\emptyset$, so we've reached a contradiction.
Thus, we may say that $A'=[-3,0]\cup\{\frac{1}{3}\}$.
Now, the boundary of $A$ is $\overline{A}\setminus \operatorname{int}A=\{\frac{n+\sqrt 2}{3n+\sqrt 3} | n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{-3,0,\frac{1}{3}\}$.
$A$ is not closed, so it is not compact, and $A$ is not an interval, so it is not connected and now we are finally done.
Are my approaches correct? I am sure that some parts can be shortened, but that's my reasoning and I want to see if it is right.

Comment: Can someone confirm if these are all right? I am having my final in a couple of days and that's why I want to make sure that I know how to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is basically $(-3,0]$ union with the set of terms of a convergent sequence outside it with limit $\frac{1}{3}$. So the closure of the union being the union of the closures (for finite unions) tells us the closure is $A \cup \{-3,\frac13\}$ as you rightly concluded. The interior is clearly $(-3,0)$ as the sequence part are just isolated points, so contains no open sets of $\Bbb R$, and the interior of $(-3,0]$ is $(-3,0)$. The boundary is the difference between closure and interior so equals $\{-3,0,\frac{1}{3}\}$ unioned with the terms of the sequence. The derived set is basically the closure minus the isolated points here so $[-3,0] \cup \{\frac13\}$.

$A$ is not compact as it is not closed and not connected as it has isolated points which are relatively clopen (all sequence terms singletons).

I don't think all the details you give are necessary. The eventual conclusions are indeed correct.